# Coloring the verbatim like environment?

Tags: latex

This is a screen capture from Pragmatic Bookshelf book.

http://img13.imageshack.us/img13/3168/screenshot20100717at123.png

It looks like that the verbatim environment with the coloring, but I'm not sure.

How can one can use color for verbatim like environment as is shown?

Using  line by line method would be a solution, but I expect a better way to go.

```
{\color{red}\begin{verbatim}
line 1
     line 2
\end{verbatim} }
\color{blue}{\begin{verbatim}
line 3
     line 4
\end{verbatim}}
```

Comment: Question is half useless because you didn't use the proper image upload functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [fancyvrb](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/) package. It includes options for colouring, so you can just use multiple Verbatim environment blocks.

Answer (score 18):

An example using fancyvbr package

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\fvset{frame=single,framesep=1mm,fontfamily=courier,fontsize=\scriptsize,numbers=left,framerule=.3mm,numbersep=1mm,commandchars=\\\{\}}

\begin{document}
   \begin{Verbatim}[label={My orange command sample output}]
# \textcolor{Orange}{My orange command}
My black output
that it can be
many lines long
but this specific \textbf{\textcolor{OliveGreen}{word}}
and the following 2
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{lines are important so they}}
\textbf{\textcolor{red}{need to be highlighted and bold}}
   \end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

[image: Sample output of this code]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work inside `tabular`; the newlines are lost as long as `commandchars` is set like that.

Comment: Haven't tested any of them, but it looks like there are a couple of similar questions with similar solutions here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119842/how-to-use-fancyvrb-verbatim-in-tabularx and here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/234292/how-to-put-verbatim-inside-multicolumn-in-tabular

Comment: Note that it is very important to define the `commandchars`. Otherwise they'll just be interpreted as normal contents. I missed them on the first glance at this answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [listings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Packages/Listings) package also:

```
\lstinputlisting[language=Ruby]{source_filename.rb}
```

Or

```
\begin{lstlisting}
\end{lstlisting}
```